# How to add verison number before deployment or push or when file changes in visual studio

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, bundling-and-minification

How to add version number dynamically to the end of the bundle URLs.

**For example:**

My bundle url: `~/Bundle/style.min.css?v=123`

I wonder, how to dynamically change or add version number before deployment or push or when `style.min.css` changes.

Is it possible or not?

Comment: Bundling already adds a hash to the URL used in the HTML to refer to the bundle. What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I removed the `Visual Studio` tag from your post, as the bundling-and-minification process in asp.net MVC is a framework feature that is not dependent on the IDE you are using.

Comment: I am using webessential bundle and i wrote the version end of the bundle url. My problem this, i made the changes on scripts or styles doesnt come if user doesnt use ctrl + f5 because of that i am trying dynamically change version number

Comment: I suppose [this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27945263/1849444) is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 4):

I'm search around and find [this article](http://www.dotnetexpertguide.com/2013/11/updated-aspnet-web-optimization-framework-and-cookieless-domain.html).

Based on it, in your `BundleConfig` you can redefine `Styles.DefaultTagFormat` and `Scripts.DefaultTagFormat`.

So if you need to change version on every build of application you can do this in `RegisterBundles` method:

```
var assemblyVersion = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version.ToString();
Styles.DefaultTagFormat = "<link href='{0}?v=" + assemblyVersion + "' rel='stylesheet'/>";
Scripts.DefaultTagFormat = "<script src='{0}?v=" + assemblyVersion + "'></script>";
```

Of course you can get version from your `Config`.

Comment: I think this method may be works but i am not using web.optimization and bundle.config. I am using bundle of the Web Essentials because of that i am not sure it works for my issue but i will try to try again. Thank you for answer